# ms access ascii conversion unable to filter

Tags: ms-access, ascii, filtering

I'm using the "ASC" function in Access (Version 365 Proplus, 32 bit).
Have created a query that uses a table with a post code that needs validating. I'm looking at the first character in the postcode, converting it to ASCII character then planning on filtering out the ones I don't want.
The formula looks like this:- 
Site_PostCode_String_Validation_P1: Asc(Left([site_postcode],1))

This works fine and converts as expected. However, when I try sorting or filtering using the Query Criteria on my Ascii list I get the following message:-
"Data Type Mismatch in Criteria Expression"

I have tried converting to a string, for example, using the below:-
Str(Asc(Left([site_postcode],1)))
But this has made no difference, get the same error message when applying criteria or sorting.
I have tried filtering using text and numbers but get the same error.

I have searched here and have Googled but can not see anything relating to the above.
Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

I tried creating a new table based on the results, thinking that this would then enable me to apply my filtering, during this process I got a more detailed error message stating error due to Null type conversion failure. So then realized that I need to make sure there were no Null entries before doing the ascii conversion. Hopefully this will be of help to someone else. Final formula now works as below:

```
IIf(IsNull([site_postcode])=-1,Null,Asc(Left([site_postcode],1)))
```

Answer (score 0):

You might simplify it a bit:

```
Site_PostCode_String_Validation_P1: Asc(Nz([site_postcode], Chr(0))
```